# c++ struct pointer to adress struct error CDCDCD

Tags: c++

```cpp
struct XYZ {
    XYZ *adress;
};

XYZ *Ex;
int main() {
    Ex = new XYZ[3];
    Ex->adress = (++Ex);
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
    Ex->adress = (++Ex);
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
    Ex->adress = (--Ex)->adress;
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
```

Output:

```
0105E424        
0105E428
0105E424
```

```cpp
struct XYZ {
    XYZ *adress;
};

XYZ *Ex;

void copy_adress(XYZ *Ex) {
    Ex->adress = (++Ex);
}

int main() {
    Ex = new XYZ[3];
    copy_adress(Ex);
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
    Ex->adress = (++Ex);
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
    Ex->adress = (--Ex)->adress;
    cout << Ex->adress << endl;
```

Output:

```
CDCDCDCD
00A3E53C
CDCDCDCD
```

Can you tell me why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: On visual studio in debug mode the pattern `CDCDCDCD` means uninitialized heap memory. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892)

Comment: Probably what happens: `Ex` points to an array. When `copy_adress` is called, the parameter `Ex` ends up incremented before it is evaluated in the expression `Ex->adress`, causing the address to be stored in the field of the second array element. Upon returning to `main`, the global `Ex` still points to the first array element (it was not incremented), so the value of `Ex->adress` is uninitialized (the compiler set it to the distinctive `0xCDCDCDCD` pattern). **However, since the behavior is undefined, this is just conjecture.**

Comment: @JaMiT Isn't this fine in c++17?

Comment: @cigien Did that change make it in? Honestly, I haven't really kept up with this aspect of the language because I avoid these kinds of expressions for style reasons / code readability. (I did finally find that C++17 note at the end of the duplicate, but that was mentioned as a proposal, which sounds like it was not definitely in when that was written.)

Comment: @JaMiT I'm not 100% sure (I rarely am), but I'm pretty sure this is ok now. Definitely not code that should be written :) anyway, I voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers behave just like regular objects when you copy them, or pass them to a function. Changes to the copy are not reflected in the original. To make the changes in a function visible, you need to take it by reference:

```
void copy_adress(XYZ *&Ex) {
   Ex->adress = (++Ex);
}
```

Now, the 2 versions are equivalent.

Comment: It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/MYumWC) only if the reference is there.

Comment: It would also avoid confusion to use a different name for the function parameter than the global variable

Answer (score 1):

(This is supplemental information, cigien answered the main question)

There was some speculation in comments about the sequencing of `Ex->adress = (++Ex)`. Since C++17, the right operand of `=` is *sequenced-before* the left operand.  And since C++11 both operands are *sequenced-before* the assignment.

So `++Ex` is completed, and then the new value of `Ex` is used for the computation `Ex->address`.  Prior to C++17 this was undefined behaviour.

The second code example does have UB but for a different reason: reading uninitialized memory: